# ASP.Net Routing: Customer ID not passing to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

see my url `localhost:55831/Customers/Edit/1/ALFKI` which i generate using `@Html.RouteLink`

```
@Html.RouteLink("Edit", "PageWithId",
new
{
    controller = "Customers",
    action = "Edit",
    id = item.CustomerID,
    page = ViewBag.CurrentPage
})
```

here is my routing code for **PageWithId** i tried two routing one after one but none work

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PageWithId",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}"
    );
```

AND

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomerEditWithId",
    url: "Customers/Edit/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
);
```

### my all routing code

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "PageWithSort",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}",
defaults: new { action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional, SortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional, CurrentSort = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
name: "PageWithId",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}"
);


routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

please some one help because when i am clicking ob this link localhost:55831/Customers/Edit/1/ALFKI then **customer id ALFKI** is not passing to edit action. i debug the edit action code and found id is getting null always. i tried few routing for edit action but no luck still.

Comment: For organisational when you have this kind of routing it is advised to use areas. They make such things very easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of routes matters. Routes are checked in order and the first matching route wins.

Because your first (`PageWithSort`) route matches any route with between 1 and 5 segments, then `/Customers/Edit/1/ALFKI`, which contains 4 segments matches, and no further routes are checked. And since `ALFKI` is being passed to the 4th segment named `SortColumn`, then it will only be bound to a parameter named `SortColumn` in your `Edit()` method (not to something named `id`)

As it stands, your `PageWithId` and `Default` routes are pointless since they can never be hit.

In additional, only the last parameter in a route definition can be marked with `UrlParameter.Optional`.

You need to create specific routes, and locate them in the correct order. Change your route definitions to (note I have omitted the `PageWithSort` route because its not clear what you want to do with that and it contains errors anyway)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomerEditWithId",
    url: "Customers/Edit/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now any url that begins with `/Customers/Edit` and contains 2 additional segments will match the `CustomerEditWithId` route, and the 3rd segment will be bound to a parameter named `page` and the 4th segment will be bound to a parameter named `id`. Therefore your method in `CustomersController` should be

```
public ActionResult Edit(int page, string id)
```

Comment: i will update my post with current routing code Monday. i would love to get more guidance to handle my situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what your `PageWithSort` route is for (that is not explained in your question), but if you place that route after `CustomerEditWithId` and change it to `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }` - i.e. remove all the `UrlParameter.Optional` then any route that contains exactly 5 segments would now match it.